# Aptana Studio 3 - whole workspace disappeared

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I've opened Aptana Studio 3 (Ubuntu 10.04) just like I did it hundreds times before (last time was yesterday). But this time I see EMPTY workspace. No projects. No error messages. Nothing. Screen attached.

I have not changed anything since the last time I used Aptana Studio (yesterday). I have not switched workspace or nothing like this. I've always had one workspace. I'm also using pydev extention - all my projects are python/django if that matters.

It happened to me AGAIN, but last time it happened on my laptopt where I wanted to format disk and re-install the system anyway so I ignored it and simply re-installed everything. Now it happened on my PC where I have a lot of important projects.

BTW, all my projects were not in default location (ie. workspace folder). I added them from other locations and workspace folder was actually empty. I don't know if this might have something to do with the issue.

Any ideas how to quickly fix this?

[image: Aptana Studio 3 Destroyed My Workspace]

Comment: Run Aptana from the command line and put the output in the post.

Comment: `File > Import... > Existing Projects into Workspace`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved the problem by manually adding the projects back to workspace. Wasn't that bad. I still don't know why they disappeared.

Comment: Anyone can do that. But is it a proper solution if everything disappears again and you have myriads of projects?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after freaking out I looked around and found

File -> Switch Workspace

and choosing my workspace loaded everything as normal.